# (Android) How do I show a hyperlink text in an email sent using "Intent.ACTION_SEND"

Tags: android, html

I am trying to send an email from an app using the ACTION_SEND intent. I wish for the email to look like this (**Notice the hyperlink text "AwesomeApp"**).

[image: Screenshot of the desired look for the email message body]

I have formatted the text as follows using a string resource value.

```
<string name="email_template">
    <![CDATA[
    <p>Dear %1$s,</p>

    <p>Please use the following link to download my app <a href "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qenetech.kukulu">AwesomeApp</a>.</p>
    <p>Cheers!</p>
    <p>%2$s</p>
    ]]>
</string>
```

And the java code that starts the ACTION_SEND activity looks as follows.

```
String resString = String.format(
        getString(R.string.email_template),
        friendName,
        myName);

Spanned message = Html.fromHtml(resString);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ emailAddress});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
```

But the output looks like this (**Notice the missing hyperlink**)

[image: Screenshot of the actual look of the email message body]

Can someone please help me? Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: `EXTRA_TEXT` is supposed to be plain text. Use `EXTRA_HTML_TEXT` for an optional version of the text with formatting: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_HTML_TEXT

Comment: Thanks, CommonsWare. But that removed the entire message. Do I need to edit the string resource for HTML_EXTRA_TEXT inputs?

Comment: I think you're supposed to pass the HTML, not the `Spanable`, in case you were passing in the `Spannable`.

Comment: I tried giving it the string directly from the resource but now it simply just doesn't open the activity at all. I will try to figure it out. This is a very great lead. Thank you so very much. I couldn't find anything so far for days.